# Alignment of components in panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I need to align components (2 `JTextField`s and 1 `JTextArea`) vertically in a `JPanel`, then position this panel in center of a already defined frame.

I want exactly like this.

[image]

I tried to do this by setting different layouts to panel, but I cannot get it to work.  In the code below, it is fine without anything anything to the panel.  If I add components to the panel it behaves differently.  The components are displayed horizontally in the panel.

```
public class DialogboxExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayout Example X_AXIS");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel lblPhone = new JLabel("Name");
        lblPhone.setBounds(65, 68, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPhone);

        JTextField  textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(136, 65, 247, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblEmailId = new JLabel("Category");
        lblEmailId.setBounds(65, 115, 70, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEmailId);

        JTextField textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(136, 112, 247, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Description");
        lblAddress.setBounds(65, 162, 150, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAddress);

        JTextArea  textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_1.setBounds(136, 157, 300, 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_1);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().add( panel, "Center");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want the `JTextField`s and the `JTextArea` to be stacked vertically.

Can someone please help me on this?

If I add a `GridLayout` to the panel it works well, but the component size is same for all 3 components.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 1):

1. *"I tried to do this by setting different layouts to panel"* It is rare that a GUI will use just one layout. In this one, I'd probably use a `GridBagLayout` (**not** a `GridLayout`) for the labels and text fields / area), then put that panel in another `GridBagLayout` to center it in the `JFrame`. (If I understand the requirement correctly, which I'm not certain I do.)
2. It becomes more complicated still if using a `JLabel` for the `Description` as opposed to a `TitledBorder`.
3. `setBounds(..)` will be ignored using any layout worth using. Specify columns to suggest a width for text fields and columns and rows for a text area.
4. `DialogboxExample` is not very accurate, given a `JFrame` is used to display the GUI. It's likely it should instead be using a `JDialog`, but sticking with the frame might result in something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrew, Could you please provide the code for the above frame by setting the components to the panel.As i need a panel object to set it the center of the frame in my application.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!! It worked for me with the first mentioned point